# Is there an "old work" NM cable clamp for metal boxes?

Tags: old-work

I'm trying to add an additional outlet below a metal box.

I was gonna tie on to that circuit and just drop the romex down the wall (it's about 3' off the ground), install an old work box and go about my business.  Then I realized this was a metal box and I would need a protector/clam for the NM cable.

Obviously I can't get to the other side of the metal box to screw on this style (pictured below) as one would normally do.  But I assume there has to be some sort of old work grommet style clamp as well right?

To sum up, "existing metal box that I can only access the inside of and I want to knock out a hole in the bottom and drop down some Romex 14/2 to add an old work box below".

[image: NM Cable Clamp]

Comment: Usually metal boxes come with the cable clamps inside them.

Comment: This is OLD and I would be knocking out a new hole in the bottom.

Comment: I think so... will have to go look and see if I can find one!

Thanks!